# Why can you assign null to a Nullable variable?

Tags: c#, nullable

Why the line below compile ? For me, `Nullable<double>` is a  struct and we can't assign a variable of this type the value "null".

```
        Nullable<double> someVar = null;
```

The assignation operator is not supposed to be overridable but maybe it is some syntax sugar and the compiler knows it has to change it to ?

```
        Nullable<double> someVar = new Nullable<double>();
        someVar.Value = null;
```

Comment: Is this an existential question?

Comment: I think it might be...

Comment: There is no syntactic sugar in what you wrote. AKAIK.

Comment: @user3185569: No; `null` in this case is syntactic sugar for `new Nullable<double>()`.

Comment: @SLaks I can't seem to verify that using Roslyn: http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmANwHswAExgBZABQBKZq3ayZstgDlgRasVQAeQX0JFUAPhgg+6VADUqAJxgBeGBBVEcC9gT58iMArZjJLwVGcXGHkFMAAzMQIJUNkASGNTC2s7AEYgtgBfbEygA==

Comment: @user3185569: That's because the decompiler has the same sugar.  Look at the IL: `IL_0003: initobj valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable\`1<float64>`

Comment: @SLaks I see the constructor called in later stage: `IL_0014: call instance void valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable 1<float64>::.ctor(!0)`

Comment: @user3185569: That's from `someVar = 1;`

Comment: @user3185569, assigning null to a struct is incorrect and it is even wrong; that's why i talked about syntaxic sugar (= some magic to make an invalid expression valid :) ).

Comment: @user3185569 `null` _is_ `new Nullable<double>()`.

Comment: @SLaks So `initobj` is a command responsible for calling the default constructor for a struct?

Comment: @user3185569: Yes.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.initobj

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler and language specification have special magical support that makes the `null` literal convertible to `Nullable<T>`.

The [spec says](https://github.com/ljw1004/csharpspec/blob/f12213c4ffe77a51dbc5412250bef6af75333f32/expressions.md#expression-classifications):

> - A null literal. An expression with this classification can be implicitly converted to a reference type or nullable type.

Answer (score 4):

It's on the specification.

Section 6.1.5 says:

> **6.1.5 Null literal conversions**
>
> An implicit conversion exists from the null literal to any nullable type. This conversion produces the null value (§4.1.10) of the given nullable type

And 4.1.10 says:

> **4.1.10 Nullable types**
>
> A nullable type can represent all values of its underlying type plus an additional null value. A nullable type is written T?, where T is the underlying type. This syntax is shorthand for System.Nullable, and the two forms can be used interchangeably.
>
> ...
>
> **Implicit conversions are available from the null literal to T? (§6.1.5) and from T to T? (§6.1.4)**

(bold is mine)